# Python Pandas (read xlsx and append)

Tags: python, pandas, append

i want to read some columns of an excel-file and finally append them to a csv-Data.
The problem is, that the columns-names has some small difference.

For example:

'Voltage L1 (V)' and in the next Data it is named 'Voltage L1 m (V)'

```
Exceldata = pd.read_excel(str(Dateien[1]), header=[2,3])
print Dateien[1]
Exceldata = Exceldata.ix[ :, ['Voltage L1 (V)']]
print Exceldata
```

The script get an error if the columnname is different.
Is it possible that the column name begins just with Volatge?

Many Thanks 
A.Boss

Comment: you can filter the df or find the columns of interest: `voltage_col = Exceldata.columns[Exceldata.columns.str.contains('Voltage')]` and then do `Exceldata = Exceldata.ix[ :, voltage_col]`

Comment: I think it's the right way , but now my DataFrame is empty

Comment: can you edit your question with the output from `Exceldata.columns.tolist()` as the spelling could not be what you think it is due to embedded spaces

Comment: Forget the first comment it is wrong.It works with one header. How can i do this with two header (MultiIndex). Thanks so much.

Comment: You'll need to post more information, the output from `Exceldata.info()` and Exceldata.columns.tolist()` I don't speculate without seeing evidence

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1442 entries, 0 to 1441
Columns: 112 entries, End time to Unnamed: 111
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(111)
memory usage: 647.8+ KB

Comment: The first row is unimportant. Row 2 is the first header for example Voltage and row 3 is the second header for example 'min' 'max' and 'avg'